# How to Find the Minimum Distance of a Ternary Linear Code

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

Let $C$ be the ternary linear code with parity check matrix

$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
What is the minimum distance of $C$, denoted $d(C)$?

From my understanding, it has to do with the linear dependent columns of the matrix, but I do not know how to solve this problems.

Comment: One of the columns is all-zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Therefore the $d(C)=0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I will change this column if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The code is given by $C=\{ vH \mid v\in{\Bbb F}_3^4\}\subseteq {\Bbb F}_3^5$, where all vectors are row vectors.

Consider the nonzero linear combinations of the columns of $H$.

Two different columns are not linearly independent (in this case one column would be the $\Bbb F_3$-multiple of another). Thus the minimum distance cannot be $2$.

Next consider three different columns of $H$. If you can linearly combine three columns to $0$, the minimum distance will be $3$.

And so on.

The smallest number of such linear combinations  is the minimum distance of $C$.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer! So if we have a zero column, the distance is $1$. If we have two identical columns, the distance is $2$. If we have two columns that are a linear combination of a third, this distance is $3$. The minimum distance is just the smallest distance. Is that correct?

Comment: This is the check matrix so
$$C=\{v\in\Bbb{F}_3^5\mid Hv^T=0\}.$$ What you say about the linear dependence of columns is correct. But I think that an easier way to answer this question is to find a generator matrix. After all, this code is 1-dimensional.